# Thermodynamics explaining the cold wall sensation

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation, thermal-conduction

Let's consider a 16 m² room (4m x 4m x 3m height cube) containing air at 20°C. Let's say the walls of the cube are at a constant temperature $T_{w}$.

There is a well-known effect called "cold-wall sensation":

- if the walls are at nearly the same temperature (20°C), then everything is ok
- if the walls temperature is significantly lower (say, $T_{w}$ = 15°C), then, even if the room temperature is still 20°C (measured with a thermometer at, say, a 5 cm distance from the wall), then a human person inside the room will feel much colder than 20°C ("cold-wall sensation").

**How to explain the physics / thermodynamics behind this fact?**

I don't think it can be explained by radiation: the walls don't specifically radiate in this case.

What thermodynamical model can we make at the skin level to explain this sensation? Is it a flow of colder air? I don't think this is the reason: we can feel this cold-wall sensation without significant convection of air (can be confirmed with an anemometer, or see the lack of movement of a lighter-than-feather object near the walls).

Are there research papers that give a thermodynamics model / explanation for this effect?

Comment: “*I don't think it can be explained by radiation: the walls don't specifically radiate in this case.*” Everything radiates, and the temperature difference you’ve given corresponds to a radiative flux difference of >25 watts per square meter of exposed skin, sensed by an occupant. Please clarify why you’re not incorporating this into your analysis.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I thought it would be negligible because T_wall < T_room so the wall doesn't radiate to the room. Are you considering radiation flux between skin (37°C) and wall (15°C) or between room air (20°C) and wall (15°C)? Maybe you're right! I would be interesting for an answer about radiation.

Comment: I used the temperature difference you gave in your question (20°C vs. 15°C) to calculate the maximum difference in incoming radiative flux from the surroundings. This is not a complete heat transfer analysis, but it does indicate a problem with hand-waving radiation away as an explanation, since the typical metabolic output is only about 100 W.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly an effect of radiation, thats much more efficient for small temperature differences than transport. The finger and lips skin detects radiation temperatur differences of around 1/10 C. Its not so false to describe this effect as cold radiation, as it is feeled that way.

The difference between sitting with the back to a stone wall or glas window is striking, because glas is a good reflector in the infrared.

For this reason, a window of 4mm glas with about 5 W/(m^2 K ) has the same loss  as a 500 mm compact stone wall.

Historically, carpets, mirrors and tapestry were simple methods to reduce radiation losses to the walls in stone buildings.

Secondly, constant temperatur difference between heating device and cold walls imply  a constant cold stream along the floor, main cause of cold feet.

The  imperial Romans introduced the floor heating; besides ship building the other reason, why there are no trees around the mediterranian.

Comment: I don't understand the "cold radiation" : is this a metaphor or a real physics concept?  Also about `The difference between sitting with the back to a stone wall or glas window is striking, because glas is a good reflector in the infrared.`, can you give more details? Which difference are you speaking about (in the case of summer temperatures or winter temperatures ?). Thank you for your answer, but currently it's a bit vague and hand-waving, maybe can you add equations to explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the wall is close to the skin, where it could decrease the temperature of the air near the skin, I believe this is primarily radiation cooling than convection cooling of the skin, the latter primarily controlled by the air temperature close to the skin (20 C).

The normal skin temperature of a human body is in the range 33-37 C. That means the skin is radiating (losing) heat to all surfaces in the room at a temperature below this range. The lower the temperature (e.g., the cold wall vs the room temperature wall) the greater the rate of heat transfer away from the skin and the "cooler" the skin will feel.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lower temperature of the walls the air temperature in the vicinity of the walls is lower than the temperature in the middle of the room. This is due to the heat moving from higher temperatures to lower temperatures.

The image below gives an idea of what that looks like.

[image: Thermal resistance of a wall]

[See more detailed explanation of the thermal resitance](https://www.ques10.com/p/15772/discuss-electrical-analogy-of-combined-heat-conduc/)

Comment: If the thermometer (which is 5 cm from the wall) gives 20°C, this doesn't explain the cold-wall sensation.

Comment: I do not know enough of the biological aspects of the sensation to have a comprehesive answer on this. Perhaps it has something to do with the walls acting as a sort of heat sink for the heat emitted by the perosn in the room, but this is just a suggestion.